# c# deferred evaluation and returned values

Tags: c#, if-statement, return, deferred, func

Considering the examples below, I'm confused about why the result for the first example is 4, 8, 6 and the second is 4, 8, 3 ? To me in the first example, only succ(3) and dub(4) are evaluated, and y should be 3? Can someone please help to explain how it works? Many thanks!

Example one:

```
public class Hello {
   public static void Main(string[] args) {
     int y = 0;
     Func<int,bool> even = (n) => { return n%2 == 0; }; 
     Func<int,int> dub = (n) => { y += 2; return n + n; };
     Func<int,int> succ = (n) => { y += 1; return n + 1; };

     Func<bool, int, int, int> if1 = (c, t, f) => c? t: f;

     y = 0;
     var a1 = if1(even(3), dub(3), succ(3));
     var a2 = if1(even(4), dub(4), succ(4)); 
     Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", a1, a2, y);   
   }
 }
```

Second example:

```
public class Hello {
public static void Main(string[] args) {
  int y = 0;
  Func<int,bool> even = (n) => { return n%2 == 0; }; 
  Func<int,int> dub = (n) => { y += 2; return n + n; };
  Func<int,int> succ = (n) => { y += 1; return n + 1; };

  Func<Func<int,bool>, Func<int,int>, Func<int,int>, Func<int,int>> if2 = (c, t, f) => (n) => { if (c(n)) return t(n); else return f(n); };

   y = 0;
   Func<int,int> x = if2(even, dub, succ); 
   var c1 = x(3);
   var c2 = x(4);
   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", c1, c2, y);
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it using a debugger? Continue to press F11 and you'll have your answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing two different things:

- The conditional operator
- Method arguments

All method arguments are evaluated before the method is called, even if they inside the method end up not being used.

So the fact that you are using the conditional operator *inside* the method has no bearing on the arguments, they are all evaluated.

So this call:

```
var a1 = if1(even(3), dub(3), succ(3));
```

Will evaluate all of the following:

- `even(3)`
- `dub(3)`
- `succ(3)`

before the method is actually called. If you instead of the direct result had returned a method that could be called to obtain the results you would have true deferred code (in this scenario) but I daresay the code would start to look really ugly.

```
                                   v---v
Func<int, Func<int>> dub = (n) =>  () => { y += 2; return n + n; };
Func<int, Func<int>> succ = (n) => () => { y += 1; return n + 1; };
Func<bool, Func<int>, Func<int>, int> if1 = (c, t, f) => c ? t() : f();
           ^-------------------^                              ^^    ^^
```

Additionally, as [@atlaste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031591/atlaste) says in the comment to your question, debugging would reveal how this works, you would see that before you step into `if1` you would step through all of the other methods.

Comment: Its called the conditional operator.

Comment: Thank you ! I don't have a debugger for now.. I used Dump() but that's not helping much. Can I ask how example is different from example one? To me they are only different syntax..

Comment: @user3735871 Your example doesn't defer calling the argument functions, while Lasse's does. Lasse is passing the *function*, while you are passing the return value of the function - that means he can evaluate the functions at will, while in your case, they have to be evaluated before passing their return values to the `if1` function. When calling Lasse's `if1`, you'd do something like `if1(even(3), () => dub(3), () => succ(3))` - note the wrapping function. You might also want to change the first argument to `Func<bool>` as well, but since `even` is pure, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Luaan Thanks! Do you mean that in the example above, because it's passing functions at `if2`, so that at `var c1 =x(3)` , only one function (succ in this case) will be evaluate?

Comment: @user3735871 Yes, because you're passing the function itself, not its return value. The evaluation of the function only happens when you do the `t()` - just as with any other method call.